# Can you convert a list to df and retain part of the list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of objects and want to make them into a data frame with the original tuple retained in it's own column.

```
L = [item(ABC, 123), item(DEF, 456), item(GHI, 789)]
```

I am looking to make a DF like:

```
Letters    Numbers     Item
ABC         123               item(ABC, 123)
DEF         456               item(DEF, 456)
GHI         789               item(GHI, 789)
```

Comment: What is `item`?  Is that a class?  If so, you have a set of objects, not a set of tuples.  That doesn't mean it can't be done, but we'd need to know more about the class.

Comment: You're right I guess it's and object. Updating the question.

Comment: Again, we can't answer without knowing what the class looks like.  You have to know how to pull "ABC" and 123 out of the object.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this :

```
list_of_tuples = [('ABC', 123), ('DEF', 456), ('GHI', 789)]

letters = [item[0] for item in list_of_tuples]
numbers = [item[1] for item in list_of_tuples]
item = [item for item in list_of_tuples]

pd.DataFrame({'Letters' : letters, 'Numbers' : numbers, 'Item' : item})
```

[image: Dataframe]

Comment: I liked the solution. However, you should follow [Python naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names).

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thanks you for the comment, I edited the answer to follow the Python naming conventions.

Comment: I updated the question to reflect item as an object. Would your solution still work?

Comment: @Trippingbillies41 Sorry, thought it would be for tuples. I believe we have to know a little more about item().